# Unable to view the html table once Visibility has done as hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on html table visible and hidden based on the file selected to upload.It works fine if i select the file with extension(".docx", ".txt") , but if i select other extension files like .pdf table is getting hidden as expected, but later if i selected the proper file again the table has to appear showing the file name which is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `onchange` is not firing up after selecting wrong extension (wrong for you) is in the line:

```
if (!blnValid) {
  ...
  document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('uploadFile_div').innerHTML;
  ...
}
```

You are replacing `input[type="file"]` element with the new one so it no longer has `onchange` event binded.

To fix it, simply give `onchange` function some name and bind it to the input file element after replacing innerHTML. Check out the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/8xKC7/1/

Comment: is their any alternative? i have used that code to clear the selected file choosen to upload on click of clear button in my code.

Comment: @user3684675 please check updated answer and link - it should get things working for you

Comment: sorry, still the issue exists, when i click on clear button , table disappears and file again cannot load the table. Please find the same in updated "http://jsfiddle.net/8xKC7/3/"

Comment: +1 to karolkochan and i think his solution should work but check out http://jsfiddle.net/dtczy/3/

Comment: @user3684675 I assume your further problem is with how jsfiddle works. Your clear button seems to fail running clearFileInputField function. I believe it is due to wrapping JavaScript code in <![CDATA[ ... ]]> by jsfiddle. I simply copied-pasted your JavaScript code into HTML area wrapping it around with <script></script> and clear button now works. 
Check this out: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8xKC7/4/